# How to disable NCQ?

Tags: windows-7, windows, sata

Is it possible to disable NCQ ([Native Command Queuing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing)) in Windows?

**Note:** NCQ is a feature of AHCI ([Advanced Host Controller Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface)), a standard that applies to SATA drives.

The reason one might want to disable NCQ is with the invention of *"I/O priority"* in Windows 7, Windows can no longer decide which operations it should run. Once a command has been queued, Windows is powerless to call it back. This can result in some pretty large I/O response times:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find your answer here, it's related to your OS and seems to be quite simple:

http://www.techenclave.com/operating-systems/how-to-disable-ncq-in-win7-157429.html

http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=499700

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable NCQ in Windows.

## Workaround

Since Native Command Queueing (NCQ) is a feature of AHCI, you *can* disable AHCI in your BIOS.

Once you've disabled AHCI, you'll lose all the features that came with it:

- Native Command Queueing
- hot-swappable drives
- [support for the `TRIM` command](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ssd-performance-tweak,2911-2.html)